# How can I change the path to android\avd in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have such exaption

```
InvalidPathException: Illegal char  at index 9: C:\Users\??????\.android\avd\1.avd (show balloon)
```

when trying to create emulator. Can I change the location of directory .android?

Comment: What is character at index 9? Your windows username?

Comment: Yes, it's my username.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Open control panel
2. Then go to System
3. Then go to Change Environment Variables of the User
4. Then click create a new environment variables
5. Create a new variable named ANDROID_SDK_HOME
6. Set its value to your Android directory, like
   `C:/users/<username>/.android`

Comment: without .android in path C:/users/<username> worked for me

Comment: I don't want to change path of SDK

Comment: Starting with Android Studio 4.2, the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable is deprecated and the default location of the emulator configuration directory is $ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT/.android/.

Answer (score 42):

I tried suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40501431/2483812) but did not work for me.
In my case I have to add a different variable so steps for me were:

1. Open *Control Panel*
2. Then go to *System and Security*
3. Then go to *System*
4. Then go to *Advanced system settings*
5. Then go to Change *Environment Variables of the User*
6. Then click create a *new* environment variables
7. ***Create a new variable named ANDROID_AVD_HOME***
8. Set its value to your Android directory, like `C:/users/<username>/.android`

Comment: Works for Android Studio 2021.1. For already existing devices - copy everything to new folder and edit 'path' in all .ini files

Answer (score 30):

How can I change the path to android\avd in my Android Studio ?

Let say you want to move avd directory from it's default `C:\users\<username>\.android\avd` to `D:\Development\avd`

1. Move avd directory to desired location (ex. `D:\Development\avd`)
2. Change or add environment variable `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` : `D:\Development\avd`

   - *On Windows: Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables*
   - If variable doesn't exits Click `New...` and fill with aforementioned data.
   - If variable exists then select variable, click on `Edit...` and replace variable value with the new path (ex. `D:\Development\avd`)
3. If you have already AVD, change avdName.ini to `D:\Development\avd\avdName` (ex. `D:\Development\avd\Nexus_S_API_22.avd`)

Comment: ...and restart Andriod Studio after changing vars

Answer (score 15):

There is a simple way to move avd(in windows):

1. open the directory: `C:\Users\Username\.android\avd`, you will find the directory named with your AVD and a .ini file
2. move the directory to your desirable path, then change the path variable in the .ini file to the new location.
3. start the Android studio, you will find that the AVD can work properly.

Comment: Good solution: an idea is to move virtual device after its creation instead of changing default avd location generally (like in most rated solution)

Answer (score 8):

Just move the emulator folder(folder that ends with .avd) to new location and keep the .ini file in same location then change the path to new location in .ini file.

No environment variable needed to be changed or added.

old path
path=C:\Users\nero\.android\avd\Android_Q.avd

new path
path=D:\androidemuators\avd\Android_Q.avd

You can keep your emulator anywhere just need to tell .ini config file where your emulator  is located.

Answer (score 4):

Simple with Image solution here, no need to edit Environment Variables here.

1. Go to `C:\Users\<PCname>\.android` and move the `avd folder` to
   your desired location. Example `D:\Programming\Android Studio\avd`
2. Open `avd folder` and edit every .ini files, each one of these is represent to your emulator.
3. Edit file location. See image below for your reference.
4. Restart your Android Studio.

These are .ini files:

[image: inifiles]

Old path:

[image: oldpath]

New path:

[image: newpath]

Comment: The better way to change the path

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The reason was that ANDROID_AVD_HOME pointed to my user directory which had a space and umlaut in it. Obviously that causes some trouble with Android Studio.
So defining a system wide ANDROID_AVD_HOME point to d:\development\avd\ solved the problem.