# Android studio doesn't detect Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I follow this guide [How can I change the path to android\avd in my Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501341/how-can-i-change-the-path-to-android-avd-in-my-android-studio)
I manage to change the path of the emulator directory, and everything was fine for a moment, was able to run my code and all of that jazz.

Restart android studio, was able to turn on the emulator but android studio doesn't detect it when I pressed run.

[image]

Deleting the emulator and installing a fresh one works, until I restarted android studio.

Flutter devices and Flutter doctor doesn't detect it also[image]

Edit: I forgot to mention that I noticed the app create another .android folder in its original C:\User\Username\ location where abdkey and abdkey.pub is stored.

I have followed this link as well [Android studio - flutter: No Connected Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991298/android-studio-flutter-no-connected-devices) still didn't work.

Comment: what will happen when you run command "adb devices"?

Comment: It only shows "List of devices attached" and nothing else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991298/android-studio-flutter-no-connected-devices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio - flutter: No Connected Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991298/android-studio-flutter-no-connected-devices)

Comment: No, it does not. I have added the ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_AVD_HOME path to make sure I didn't miss anything. I have already added the flutter/bin to both my user and system variable since the start anyway. Sad to say it didn't work.

Comment: So, I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492762/13192893 again. Except this time, I reset all of my paths and only added the ANDROID_AVD_HOME. It works, except flutter devices still doesn't detect it. However, I can run my code now which is something.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue but when I ran `flutter doctor`, I was getting an error related to adb:

```
[☠] Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Exception: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: /Users/josephmuller/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

I fixed it by opening the Activity Monitor on my Mac and quitting all `adb` processes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, it's been two years since this bug has occured and I haven't encountered it since. I don't remember how I solve it or if i have at all. Point is, I can't verify if this will work or not now.